# How to add a EBS disk to the AWS Instance in the cfn-int command

Tags: java, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I need to add existing EBS disc to the windows instance in the startup.
everything already setup in the cloudformation but I need to use cfn-init and powershell script.
can someone guide me on this.

Many thanks in advance.

thanks,
Raju

Everything already setup in the cloudformation but I need to use cfn-init and powershell script.
can someone guide me on this.

Comment: What have you tried and why it does not work. Provide your template code with exact explanation why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only adding one EBS volume to a server you could be slightly risky and assume it will be added to the server as Disk Number 2 and then use the following:

```
$DiskNumber="2"
$DriveLetter="D"
$Label="EbsDrive"
Initialize-Disk -UniqueId $DiskNumber -PartitionStyle MBR
New-Partition -DiskNumber $DiskNumber -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -UseMaximumSize
Format-Volume -DriveLetter "$DriveLetter" -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "$Label" -Confirm:$false
```

If you want to add multiple disks, or just use a more robust process, then you could try to follow these instructions: [Automatically mount NVME volumes in AWS EC2](http://david-latham.blogspot.com/2021/05/automatically-mount-nvme-volumes-in-aws.html)